# Fedora 28's "JDK" is missing the compiler, javac; How do I properly install it?

Tags: java, fedora, jdk, openjdk

I installed a fresh download of Fedora Server 28 and it didn't come with Java. Fine. I ran `yum list`, and found some packages to install and installed all the most suitable looking JDK packages.

Ostensibly, "JDK" is supposed to stand for "Java Development Kit", however, even though I have all this:

> javapackages-tools-5.0.0-14.fc28.noarch
>
> java-11-openjdk-11.0.ea.22-1.fc28.i686 tzdata-java-2018e-1.fc28.noarch
>
> java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.162-3.b12.fc28.x86_64
>
> java-11-openjdk-headless-11.0.ea.22-1.fc28.x86_64
>
> java-11-openjdk-headless-11.0.ea.22-1.fc28.i686

...I have no `javac` compiler. Or, if it's there, even `find` can't find it.

I dare say, nothing called JDK should be missing the javac compiler because then it isn't much of a development kit, is it?

Do I have to get this from Oracle?!

Comment: Not certain for Fedora but on CentOS=RHEL it's java-$version-openjdk-**devel**.$arch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On fedora, you can find out which package provides a certain command using the following:

```
rpm -qf `which javac`
```

Or alternatively with yum:

```
yum provides `which javac`
```

**Edit**: Apparently `java-devel` is the package you need. (Got this from a Google search)

**Edit2:** The correct package turns out to be `yum install java-$VERSION-openjdk-devel`

Comment: The answer to the question asked, "Do I have to get this from Oracle?!" is: yum install java-<ver>-openjdk-devel ... You might update the answer for us!

Comment: I've edited it, thank you and I'm glad it worked!